# VOIP Protocols for Mobile Dialer

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, h.323

I want to make a bandwidth efficient voip dialer. Cant seem to make up my mind about which protocol to use. I see 3 main candidates SIP, H.323, IAX2. Can anyone please suggest me what to use and why? Also possibly some links or books to read more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most flexible and best Protocol is `SIP` and easy to build.

`H.323` is the most complex and difficult to build.

There is Demo App in Android API level 15 Samples folder called `SipDroid` Project which comes with android API 15 Level.You can go through that project.